# Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop Raspberry System slowly over night

Tags: raspberrypi, 21.04

System becomes slow overnight, mouse cursor jerks. Just restarting helps.
Ubuntu 21. 04 Desktop Raspberry all updates.
Problem occurs with Raspberry Pi 4 8GB.

The device runs overnight. Only the monitor is switched off. The next morning,
System very slow and looks like frozen.

Is reproducible on 3 x Raspberry Pi Four!
Problem exists since release of the version
21. 04 Desktop Raspberry.
With Ubuntu 20. 10 Raspberry and Ubuntu Budgie 21. 04 there was and there is no problem!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the built in GPU makes a big difference in most desktop use.  If the Graphics Adaptor is "unknown", it is going to be slow on graphics tasks.  There is a 3rd party package from Q-Engineering called Vulcan that makes a huge difference.  Somehow it was available in 20.04 but I had to do a complete source build and install when I upgraded to 21.04 (and noticed the massive slowdown).  There is probably lots more to this and maybe a better solution out there but this is what I had to do.  Link below (if this site permits).

https://qengineering.eu/install-vulkan-on-raspberry-pi.html